# webpack verbose error message

Tags: node.js, webpack

I was using webpack, and recently updated few packages (babel, babel-loader,..) and see an error in webpack output. but, not sure how to debug further. The application seems to work fine. I tried with various debug options, but not getting a verbose output of the error.

```
 ./node_modules/.bin/webpack  --config webpack.config.js --progress --profile --colors --display-error-details --display-reasons --debug
NODE_ENV == production :  false
6809ms build modules      
14ms seal
55ms optimize
30ms hashing
59ms create chunk assets
27ms additional chunk assets
1551ms optimize chunk assets
33ms optimize assets
83ms emit
Hash: 5be1a8485c4110c2f837
Version: webpack 1.9.8
Time: 8674ms
      Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
mww7few.ttf    78.4 kB          [emitted]   
elilql0.png    7.47 kB          [emitted]  
  client.js    3.98 MB       0  [emitted]  main
 index.html  130 bytes          [emitted]  
   [0] multi main 52 bytes {0} [built]
       factory:0ms building:3ms = 3ms
    + 387 hidden modules

ERROR in undefined
```

I am not sure what is that `ERROR in undefined`. I suspect an issue with a loader, as I updated `babel-loader`but not sure how to know more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@bsr

I recently had this same problem.  It turns out it was from HtmlWebpackPlugin.  I forgot to pass a title

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  ....
  title: 'Title'
}),
```

And on my template I had this
`<title>{%=o.htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title`

So If you use HtmlWebpackPlugin, make sure you pass all the parameters there.

Comment: thank for the hint. It is not HtmlWebpackPlugin for me though. but that gave me a hint. I will recheck for the configuration of my plugins. +1

Comment: try making a blank function, `function hello() { }` then use that as entry point, see if there's something wrong with your webpack config.  If error disappears then something about your code, otherwise you can remove each plugin.

Comment: thanks. your intuition was right. https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin/issues/50 . Also, your debugging method help me to identify the cause. thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in the webpack-html-plugin version 1.4 and was fixed in 1.5

The reason for the error is that `o.htmlWebpackPlugin.assets` is deprecated.
You should use `o.htmlWebpackPlugin.files` instead to be able to use css and manifest files:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html{% if(o.htmlWebpackPlugin.files.manifest) { %} manifest="{%= o.htmlWebpackPlugin.files.manifest %}"{% } %}>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{%=o.htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title || 'Webpack App'%}</title>
    {% if (o.htmlWebpackPlugin.files.favicon) { %}
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{%=o.htmlWebpackPlugin.files.favicon%}">
    {% } %}
    {% for (var css in o.htmlWebpackPlugin.files.css) { %}
    <link href="{%=o.htmlWebpackPlugin.files.css[css] %}" rel="stylesheet">
    {% } %}
  </head>
  <body>
    {% for (var chunk in o.htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks) { %}
    <script src="{%=o.htmlWebpackPlugin.files.chunks[chunk].entry %}"></script>
    {% } %}
  </body>
</html>
```

However there is even a simpler way.
The webpack-html-plugin 1.3+ has a feature which will inject all assets (css, favicon, javascript and manifest files) into your template.
So your configuration might look like this:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  inject: true,
  template: 'template.html',
  title: 'Custom template',
})
```

and the template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{%=o.htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title || 'Webpack App'%}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

In case somebody gets to this question and it is not an issue with htmlWebpackPlugin, IMO the actual issue is in Webpack itself that doesn't provide the correct error.

Apparently this PR attempts to solve it

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/pull/1146

> We have plugins we use that were thowing errors that were strings.
>   However the errors reporrted were
>
> Error undefined which was little to no help. Now we actually get the
>   error reporting we need.
>
> Stats now error reporting catches string errors. Some plugins appear
>   to not obey the rules on error reporting. However this makes debuging
>   a nightmare for users. Therefore the string should be allowed.